# Java scanner check if string or int

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a scanner running where the user can input either strings or integers.
There are only specific characters the user can enter such as a,e,u,r and the number can be anything. The check runs if its a letter but fails if the user enters a number.

```
String temp = scanner.next();
String[] validToken = {"x","e","u","r","+","-","/","*",};
for (String validToken1 : validToken) {
    if (temp.equals(validToken1) || temp.equals("\\d+")) {
        tokenCheck = true;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use a try catch?

Comment: Using a `Set` instead of a `String[]` will enable you to do this: `validToken.contains(temp)` and like @iNam said, if you want to check a `String` agains a regex use `matches(....)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change equals to `matches`. `matches` is used to check whether or not string matches a particular regular expression.

```
if (temp.equals(validToken1) || temp.matches("\\d+")) {
                     tokenCheck = true;
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be fixed when you replace `equals` with `matches`, because with equals you are checking if the string is literally `\d+`, it's not regex.